# Is there a free GUI software to compile Java

Tags: java

I am a total total beginner in Java actually I am .net dev trying to fix something in java.
I think I have fixed it however I need to compile the files.
I have used the dos javac etc... but i never seem to get it right.
I have 20 files to compile.

Any suggestions on a gui?

Comment: It's not DOS, it's the command line, and no, it's not an antique thing.

Comment: @hasen j: At least not at Linux/Unix.

Comment: Windows Powershell isn't DOS either :) (Nor is cmd.exe for that matter)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First I would highly recommend you get it to work with the command line. While the command line does seam to have fallen out of favour with developers these days I consider it a key skill. Many an awkward job can be significantly simplified if you know the tools at your disposal. But more importantly if you have a problem with the "GUI" tools and you don't know the basics of what is going on under the hood you will have a real problem fixing it. So what problems are you having compiling the software on the command line? If I have read you question incorrectly and you are not having problems compiling software, but are simply looking for a better method of going about it:

A "GUI" for Java development is commonly called a [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (Integrated Development Environment). This is more than a simple GUI round compiling Java files (but you can use it that way) but also project file management, highlighting and the such like. The big three in the Java world are: [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) and [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (the latter of which has freeware and payware versions, the rest are only freeware).

But that is not the end of the story if you are looking at making your build process better. What you also want to be looking at is automation (this was covered in the [Pragmatic Starter Kit Series](http://www.pragprog.com/starter_kit)). This will allow you to build, test and maybe even deploy via a script. You can simply use a .bat file but this can be rather awkward. Java has three main players in this area: [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [Gradle](http://gradle.org/).

Comment: +1 very nice and complete answer! However, there is the new "community editon" of IntelliJ IDEA that is free.

Answer (score 10):

Eclipse works as Ngu mentioned; so does [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.com/)

Comment: Do you want him to install eclipse for just compiling the already created java files?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). It's open source, and free.

There are a lot of plugins for it, some open, some commercial.

Answer (score 7):

You mean you are looking for an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) for Java. Eclipse and NetBeans are the two most popular IDEs for Java.

There are also others, for example [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/free_java_ide.html) (which was recently made free and open source).

Comment: +1 for the comment that it's recently made free. Didn't knew that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a GUI, but might help in your situation: If it's an existing project it might already have an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build file. Then you would just have to call the build file to build the project.

Answer (score 2):

Surely there must be some other build files around the place.  A "build.xml" file?  A "pom.xml" file?  A "makefile" or "Makefile"?  A shell script or batch file?

Let us know what other files there are and we can figure out what to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a `build.xml` file, you just need to use [`ant`](http://ant.apache.org/). Download it and run "ant" in a command prompt in the same directory as the build.xml file.